# Loading an XML locally into JavaScript without having a web server available?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I've made an script for processing XML: 
Extracts parts of the XML-data and displays them on a HTML-/CSS-page.

Currently I use the stringified content of some arbitrary file for doing my development. Written as a string-literal into my JavaScript.

Works great. But now comes the problem:

Of course I would like to load whatever (equal-structured) XML-files. Instead of having it in my code as a string-literal.

Normally I would load the files into my script via Ajax.
But I can't install a web-server on these computer.

I'm within an enterprise and it isn't possible to install any additional software. Restricted via group-policies etc. No chance. Forget it!

As far as I know it isn't possible to use Ajax without a web-server because Ajax communicates via the http-protocol.

So here's my questions:

I there (perhaps) a possibility to use Ajax without a web-server?

And in case of impossible:
Have I got any Ajax-alternatives to load XML-data into my script?

Comment: If you can use google chrome you can use `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to allow ajax when accessing pages from `file://` protocol

Comment: @jcubic Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. But got only the pre-installed Internet Explorer. And everything else one doesn't get here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed your xml inside script tag in your html like this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('file').innerHTML)
```

```html
<script type="text/xml" id="file">
<root><foo><bar></bar></foo></root>
</script>
```